# Bundle Install trying to install gem not in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

I have a strange problem. I cloned a working rails repository from github.

It had a gemfile with certain gems and "debugger" was not one of them.

However when i ran "bundle install" it error out

> ```
> An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot
> continue.
> Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
> ```

So i deleted the Gemlock file which had a reference to the debugger. Now i try to do "bundle install"again. I am getting the same error.

I am using ruby 2.1 and debugger is not compatible with it and everybody seems to be moving byebug. However im not able to move away from debugger as my bundler wont let me.

Any thoughts.

Comment: Looks like there's a gem in your Gemfile that's dependent on `debugger`.

Comment: How do i identify which Gem it is and what is the resolution for it. ruby 2.1 does not support debugger, so how do i get past this

Comment: In `Gemfile.lock`, you can see from the indentation which gem depends on `debugger`.